# Trigger cloud code function at an specific date

Tags: parse-platform

I have my server working perfectly with Parse-server and heroku.

One of the things I'm missing is that I want one of my cloud code functions to be called at 1:00 am each day. Is there any way I can automate this? Maybe with Parse or with another service? I just need to call that method 1 time per day.

Comment: that's really nice question. i want to do the same exact thing and i wonder if there is any way to do it. Looking forward the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

So after some research on Github and on npm packages I have found this one.

First you install `node-schedule` A cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node.

You can install it through Putty in your server with this command `npm install node-schedule`

After you install it successfully you can open your main.js file that you have your Cloud Code and paste the following code

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(' * * * * *', function(){
    console.log('This console log will run every 5 minutes');
});
```

The meaning of the stars

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    |
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

So you can have the complete code running like this if you want it to run 5 seconds (to see if its working by replacing your cloud code)

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * *', function(){
  Parse.Cloud.define("averageStars", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
  query.equalTo("movie", request.params.movie);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        sum += results[i].get("stars");
      }
      response.success(sum / results.length);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
 });
});
```

Useful links:

[node schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

Try this one and I'm waiting for your results!